# jQuery - simulate focus on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tabbing, snare

On one of the pages of our website (asp .net web forms), we are only able to tab through the controls of the page 1 time (by pressing tab key) and after that it just cycles tabbing through address bar and page tab. It only happens in IE. We are using this script and that's what's causing it:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='https://mpsnare.iesnare.com/snare.js'> </script>
```

When I remove this script, it works correctly and I can tab through the controls of the page as many times as I want. However we need to have this script on this particular page. Now I noticed one thing: once the tabbing stops working (i.e. it is only cycling through address bar and page tab), if I click in an empty area of the page then tabbing starts to work and it then always works permanently. This means, this script is removing the focus from the page. So I think what I want is that, as soon as the above script finishes whatever it is doing, I want to somehow simulate click on the empty area of the page. We are using jQuery as well. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Pick a div or another area and give it focus at the end of your script?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is your actual solution but you can do this with plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById("logo").focus()
```